# logger.debug functionality in c++

Tags: c++, logging

Is there any logging functionality in c++ which can be enabled by setting debug=True or something like that to print debug messages to stdout ?

Comment: Well there's [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/clog/), but it goes to `stderr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual trick goes like this:

```
void writeLog(const char* message); // Define elsewhere to do your logging

#ifdef DEBUG
#define Log(x) writeLog(x)
#else
#define Log(x)
#endif

// Somewhere in your main code
Log("This message is only seen if DEBUG is defined at compilation");
```

Comment: So according to the value of debug the log will be defined as something different, right ? Sorry I am a bit new to this type of function definitions.

Comment: That's right. The `#` directives are part of the preprocessor; essentially, before the code is compiled, the preprocessor will physically rewrite it. If `DEBUG` has been defined (usually as a project setting, or a switch to a command-line compiler), then `Log` gets replaced with `writeLog`; if it's not defined, `Log` is replaced with nothing, so it does nothing.

Comment: Just to be really awkward, the standard defines a symbol `NDEBUG`, that affects the `assert` macro. So if you want your logging and your assertions to be on the same switch, you can use that or else you can add some code to define `DEBUG` if `NDEBUG` is false, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically. But you can define your own methods selectively.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_MSG(msg) debug(msg)
#else
#define DEBUG_MSG(msg)
#endif
```